# php: class not found (dynamically created instance)

Tags: php, namespaces, classnotfound

I want to dynamically create instances of some classes, but I got an error saying that the class is not found (if its called dynamically from a string), otherwise if I created an instance of the class normally by typing the class name "without using strings" it will be created successfully.

the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'SiteController' not found in C:\wamp\www\framework\controllers\RouterController.php on line 31

core/Controller.php

```
namespace core;

class Controller{

    function __construct(){
        $files = glob('./' . '/*.php');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            require_once($file);   
        }
    }
}
```

controllers/RouterController.php

```
namespace controllers;

require_once("core/Controller.php");

use \core\Controller;
use \controllers\SiteController;

class RouterController extends Controller{

    private $url;
    private $controller;
    private $controllerName;
    private $action;

    function __construct($url){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->splitUrl();

        // the following is working successfully

        $this->controller = new SiteController();
        $this->controller->{"$this->action"}();

        if($this->controllerName != '' && $this->action != ''){

            // but this is not working

            $this->controller = new $this->controllerName();
            $this->controller->{"$this->action"}();
        }
    }

    private function splitUrl(){
        $url = preg_split("#/#", $this->url);
        $this->controllerName = !empty($url[0]) ? ucfirst($url[0])."Controller" : null;
        $this->action = !empty($url[1]) ? $url[1] : "index";
    }
}
```

controllers/SiteController.php

```
namespace controllers;

class SiteController{

    public function index(){
        echo "this is index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is error not on line `$this->controller = new SiteController();` ?

Comment: @splash58 no its on `$this->controller = new $this->controllerName();`

Comment: Have you tried adding the namespace to the dynamically created string? (eventhough it is in the same namespace)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer this will throw a syntax error

Comment: @Mohammad Have you started with a balckslash?
`'\controllers\SiteController'`

Comment: @PhilippMaurer yes of course